# Android: DayDream in Application

Tags: android, dreamservice

I'm developing application in which I'm using DreamService. But built-in options only give start daydreaming while charging and docking. Is there any solution to invoke daydreaming during executing application( while device is inactive for a while, say, 5 sec)?

Answer (score 2):

*Answer is a year late and doesn't address the inactivity for 5 sec issue, but still might be useful...*

Add the following ***DreamNow.java*** file to your project and extend your Activity with the *DreamNow* class.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

/**
 * To use, replace "extends Activity" in your activity with "extends DreamNow".
 *
 * From the Google Android Blog Daydream example.
 */
public class DreamNow extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        try {
            // Somnabulator is undocumented--may be removed in a future version...
            intent.setClassName("com.android.systemui",
                                "com.android.systemui.Somnambulator");
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        } catch (Exception e) { /* Do nothing */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: This stopped working with Android 13. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

As `DreamService` inherits from `Service` it should be possible to dynamically start them by using [startService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29).

Comment: When I tried this, the `onStartCommand` method was called in the `DreamService` subclass but not the daydream lifecycle methods like `onAttachToWindow` and `onDreamingStarted`.